# IF + ISNUMBER + SEARCH Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, if

I am trying to create a formula that will enter specific texts, when the cell had certain keywords. I've seen a formula here, but I can't seem to add more texts to it.

What should be my formula below? My formula doesn't seem to work:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Mammals",A1)),"Mammals",""),(SEARCH("Reptiles",A1)),"Reptiles",""),(SEARCH("Birds",A1)),"Birds",""))
```

Keywords = Text

- Mammals Horse = Mammals
- Cat Mammals = Mammals
- Reptiles Frog = Reptiles
- Dove Birds = Birds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to separate the `IF`, the second and third `SEARCH` functions with the commas thinking that they will somewhat interact is wrong. You must include them in your IF statement. `IF` functions can be nested inside an `IF` function. I have slightly modified your formula to include nested `IF` and `ISNUMBER` functions

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Mammals",A1)),"Mammals",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Reptiles",A1)),"Reptiles",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Birds",A1)),"Birds","")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! This actually worked! I was just wondering, since I will have a lot of keywords, would it be possible to do a search for an entire column and match it from to another column as well?

Something like this? But this formula didn't work --> =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Keywords!A:A, A2)), Keywords!B:B, "")

Comment: @Pat If the question has been successfully answered, mark it as solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers). Regarding your "proposed" formula, I think it is better to use the [FILTER function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759).

Answer (score 1):

**If you are on Excel for Microsoft 365, here are a few options for you:**

*If the category is always the first word in the text:*

This formula in the first row (adjust range as necessary):

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1:A4," ")
```

[image]

---

*If the word is *somewhere* in the text (not necessarily first word) but you potentially have a much longer list of categories:*

This formula in the first row (adjust range as necessary):

```
=XLOOKUP(A1:A4,E1:E3,E1:E3,"",-1)
```

[image]

---

**If you have an older version of Excel**

Put your list of categories in a separate range and *sort them alphabetically*. Then put this formula in the first row and copy it down to the remaining rows:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$E$1:$E$3,1,TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one +10 ☺,,,, but VLOOKUP has some issue !!

Comment: Thanks, @RajeshSinha. Curious what you mean. I'm sure there will be problems with some data with approximate VLOOKUP, but for the data in the qn, I think it's ok.

Comment: ,,,, yeah no issue,,,, I was mistaken ☺

Comment: Thank you, but this is not really what I'm looking for. I edited the question so it will be clearer. I need a formula to automatically enter a text to certain keywords found in the cell.

Comment: That's what my answer does. The difference is that my answer allows you to manage the list of keywords more easily and not have to embed them in the formula, which will quickly get difficult to manage if the list of keywords grows.